# Wordpress ping automatically when content is viewed

Tags: pinging

Besides ping when post is published, I need my wordpress website to ping automatically when page or posts is viewed (i have imported lots of posts from old html).

I don't know what is the format in pinging. a guy told me that ping to some type of website is as simple as running URL like below (is this true?):

```
http://www.pingserver.com/[URL-TO-PING]
```

how about pinging to pingomatic?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to do this? to keep track of every time you get a view? you can set up google analytics (www.google.com/analytics/) and it'll do it much better than ping.

unless you're trying to trigger some sort of event per view, in which case you could set up a RESTful get request that triggers it?

finally, if you're really set on using ping, php comes with support for a ping library: http://www.codediesel.com/php/ping-a-server-using-php/

Comment: no, not to keep track. I dont need google analytic. I mean pinging to ping server like Ping-O-Matic to let them know my website has updated.

Comment: in your question you said you want to ping per view, not per post.

Comment: i mean when content is viewed, just like Rules module feature in Drupal. content means blog posts and any other post types

Answer (score 0):

unlike drupal, wordpress is lack of workflow

the best solution is to integrate drupal with wordpress so you have both feature